# vuejs 3 yup type according validations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, yup

hello i have a little problem

that is, I will do a validation, but I want to make validations according to the member type, so if it is corporate, the tax number will be mandatory, but the phone number not

if it is individual it will be the opposite

a phone validations when the value is false
if value is true then only tax validations

```
setup() {
const value = ref(false);
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  phone: Yup.string().trim().required().label("Phone"),
  tax: Yup.string().trim().required().label("Tax"),
});

const { handleSubmit } = useForm({ validationSchema });
const submit = handleSubmit(async (values) => {
  console.log("personName:", values);
});
return {
  validationSchema,
  submit,
  value,
};
```

},

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `memberType` to the validation then you can do something like this:

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  memberType: Yup.string().required(),
  phone: Yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .label("Phone")
    .when("memberType", {
        is: "individual",
        then: Yup.string().required("Must enter phone number")
     }),
  tax: Yup
    .string()
    .trim()
    .label("Tax")
    .when("memberType", {
        is: "corporate",
        then: Yup.string().required("Must enter tax number")
     }),
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what is the "membertype" here, does it need to fill in its content, I don't quite understand please help

Comment: @kadirklc If you click on "individual" the value of memberType will be set to "individual", like `<button id="memberType" value="individual">Individual</button>`, same for corporate/institutional

Comment: this button did not change the value